# Set option in same order in select2 version 3.2 Dynamically without sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I want to set the same order in my select2 dropdown dynamically as per the value which i am passing using JS but it is sorting the option as per dropdown automatically.Need Help.

Below is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.2/select2.min.css" />

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.2/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <select style="width: 500px;" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="4">four</option>
    <option value="1">one</option>
  </select>
  <button id="d">set</button>
</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#d").click(function(){
        $("select").select2("val", ["1","2"]);    
    })


  $("select").select2();

  $("select").on("select2:select", function (evt) {
    var element = evt.params.data.element;
    var $element = $(element);

    $element.detach();
    $(this).append($element);
    $(this).trigger("change");
  });
})



</script>
</html>
```

The Output which i am getting on button click is 
Output
[image]

But the output which i need is Expected Output
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using the  `$("select").val(['2', '1']);` the function would add the options according to there position inside there `select` so to get the output you want try changing the selects options to what you wich them to be showing

you need to change your html from :

```
<select style="width: 500px;" multiple="multiple">
<option value="2">two</option>
<option value="4">four</option>
<option value="1">one</option>
```

to

```
<select style="width: 500px;" multiple="multiple">
<option value="1">one</option>
<option value="2">two</option>
<option value="4">four</option>
```

see example

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#d").click(function(){
        $("select").val(['2', '1']);
        $("select").trigger('change');    
    })


  $("select").select2();

  $("select").on("select2:select", function (evt) {
    var element = evt.params.data.element;
    var $element = $(element);

    $element.detach();
    $(this).append($element);
    $(this).trigger("change");
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <select style="width: 500px;" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="4">four</option>
  </select>
  <button id="d">set</button>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply i have seen your above code you have given value $("select").val(['2', '1']); so the dropdown should be two , one but it is showing one,two that's the problem it is sorting according to dropdown value how to solve that?

Comment: you shoud change the positioning of the option in the select html, see the example

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: see the answer and mark it as resolved and give it an upvote if it fix your issue